# Remove .001 from mesh name duplicates

Tags: mesh, objects, data-blocks

I bake all my OCC/NRMs inside substance painter using _high _low suffix.  If I want to bake floaters, I must name said floaters with the same name as the object I want to bake them onto (E.G) MESH > Gun_handle_high FLOATER > Gun_handle_high

I cant do this inside blender.  When I try to name a mesh with a duplicate name I get .001 .002 .003 etc at the end of the mesh name.  How do I stop this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: When ever you duplicate an object in blender it will generate a unique name.  If I'm understanding your question correctly just rename the object. delete the".001" and add your own suffix.

Comment: I have tried that, it immediately adds the .001 back.  I need 6 objects with the same name -> Bolt_high.  But blender renames them Bolt_high.001 .002 .003 etc etc.  If blender is not able to do something as simple as allowing duplicate names for those who bake using suffix, im done.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit like asking "how do I give two files the exact same name, and put them in the exact same folder on my computer?" Just like files, separate meshes must have unique names... otherwise, neither you nor Blender knows which mesh is which.

---

**Firstly, lets define our terms.** A "Mesh" is a collection of vertices. Meshes have to live inside an "Object." An "Object" is a container for vertices. An object can contain literally any arrangement of vertices; connected, unconnected, polygons, individual points, etc. All those vertices are considered one mesh when they are inside an object, even if they aren't connected to each other. You can think of vertices a little like letters. If vertices -> letters, then polygons -> words, text -> mesh, and object -> document. (It doesn't work perfectly because you don't name your text separately from the document it's in, but Blender does do this with meshes and objects).

Each object must have a unique name, and each mesh must have a unique name. Typically, a mesh gets its first name from the object it's created in, but it doesn't have to.

---

**To answer your question, you have two options.** You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to join the meshes in any selected objects into one object (Blender will put them in the "active" object, and then delete the empty ones). This takes all the separate collections of vertices and puts them in the same container. This also gives them all the same mesh name... because they are all one mesh. To continue our files analogy, this method would be like cutting the text from one document and pasting at the end of another other document, and deleting the empty document. You now only have one container, but you still have the text from both documents.

Your other option is to use some other method to give unique names. Maybe it makes sense for your meshes to be in separate objects. In that case, there's likely a descriptive way to name them that will also uniquely identify them.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Unfortunately this doesn't help my situation - Like I said, I use a suffix to bake my OCC/NRMs which requires me to have duplicate names.  It's an essential part of my work flow.  It can be done is 3dsmax with no issues at all, I can't see why blender wont do it?

Comment: I think I'm confused... Which of these examples are you asking about? 1) How to name one object "Roof_OCC" and another object "Roof_NRM?" or 2) How to name two different objects both "Wall_OCC" and two other objects both "Wall_NRM"?

Comment: OK - Say I have 2 Objects in my scene.  One lowpoly box and the same box again, but only it's the highpoly version.  If I want to bake the highpoly detail of my box onto the lowpoly box I must name the low poly box - Box_low and the highpoly - Box_high.  If I want to bake extra detail onto my lowpoly box, say a few screws or greebles, I would have to name those Box_high also.  But I can't do this in blender without .001 being added to the object name.  Do you understand?  this is a suffix work-flow and probably one of the best baking methods, it eliminates hours from your workflow.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, but it sounds ill advised, to me. Regardless, there is no way to name things that way in Blender. Blender requires unique names. If you're trying to get meshes out of Blender in order to bake them in Substance Painter, you could probably write a python script that will systematically export each mesh, stripping the ".###" off the end of the name as it saves each mesh.

Comment: Matt, there has got to be a a way to do this without Python.  Thanks for trying to help me out :)

Comment: Lol... maybe there "has to be," but it doesn't exist. You might be able to put the names you want into a custom property on the object, but you'll still have to use python to extract them when you export, and use them for naming your exported objects.

Answer (score 2):

For people still looking for this subject:

Right now there is no need to give floaters the same name as the high poly mesh if it comes to baking normals (from Blender) in Substance Painter.

I have just checked it and it is enough to join (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) all the floaters and the high poly mesh - looks like everything works well.